# Why does running "echo $-" output "himBH" on the bash shell?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm using macOS. When I open a bash shell and execute `echo $-`, it outputs `himBH`. What does that mean?

Comment: Have you tried reading [the BASH manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html)? More specifically, look at the "Special Parameters" section.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It shows your Builtin Set Flags. `man bash` then look for SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS and then look for the `set subsection`. You will find the meanings of all those flags:

```
h: Remember the location of commands as they are looked up for execution.  This is enabled by default.
i: interactive
m: Monitor mode.  Job control is enabled
B: The shell performs brace expansion (see Brace Expansion above).  This is on by default
H: Enable !  style history substitution.  This option is on by default when the shell is interactive.
```